# assertTrue exception in spring boot application oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, crud

I have a spring boot application with `cooperator` and `student` models (among others). they have a @oneToMany relationship from cooperator side and @ManyToOne from student side

cooperator class:

```
@Entity
public class Cooperator{
    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    private Set<Student> student;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cooperator", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<Student> getStudent() {
       return this.student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Set<Student> students) {
       this.student = students;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        try {
            this.student.add(student);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {    
            this.student = new HashSet<Student>();
            this.student.add(student);
        }
    }
}
```

student class:

```
@Entity
public class Student{
    private String studentID;

    public void setStudentID(String value) {
       this.studentID = value;
    }
    @Id
    public String getStudentID() {
        return this.studentID;
    }

    private Cooperator cooperator;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    public Cooperator getCooperator() {
       return this.cooperator;
    }

    public void setCooperator(Cooperator cooperator) {
       this.cooperator = cooperator;
    }
}
```

I am testing the relationship in the following way:

```
    @Test
    public void cooperatorStudent() {
        String studentID = "260632353";
        String firstname = "Saleh";
        String lastname = "Bakhit";
        Student student1 = service.createStudent(studentID, firstname, lastname, cooperator);
        assertEquals(cooperator, student1.getCooperator());

        studentID = "260632350";
        firstname = "testFirst";
        lastname = "testLast";
        Student student2 = service.createStudent(studentID, firstname, lastname, cooperator);
        assertEquals(cooperator, student2.getCooperator());

        Set<Student> cooperatorStudents = cooperator.getStudent();
        assertTrue(cooperatorStudents.contains(student1));
        assertTrue(cooperatorStudents.contains(student2));

    }
```

The problem is the assertTrue statements are failing even though `cooperatorStudents` actually containts both `student` objects.

Any help as to why that is is very much appreciated.

`EDIT`

I add the `student` to the `cooperator`'s `Set<Student> student` in `createStudent`, here's the code for it:

```
    @Transactional
    public Student createStudent(String studentID, String firstname, String lastname, Cooperator c) {
        if(!checkArg(studentID) || !checkArg(firstname) || !checkArg(lastname) || !checkArg(c)) {
            throw new NullArgumentException();
        }

        Student student = new Student();

        student.setStudentID(studentID);
        student.setFirstName(firstname);
        student.setLastName(lastname);
        student.setIsProblematic(false);

        student.setCooperator(c);
        c.addStudent(student);

        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
```

Also adding @override hashcode and equals give stackoverflow when creating the second student

Comment: Your code is not complete. Try debugging and see what's happening.

Comment: As far as I haven't overlooked anything, you do not add the student objects to the cooperator in the test-method.

Comment: I do add the student. see the edit above

Answer (score 0):

Then you want compare objects you have to override "equals" and "hashcode" methods. By default every class instance "object" will be unique despite their field are the same. Good explanation: https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java

Comment: The problem is when I do that i get another failure: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ca.mcgill.ecse321.academicmanager.model.Cooperator.course, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: I actually get a stackoverflow.. see the edit in the post

Answer (score 0):

As far as I haven't overlooked anything, you do not add the student objects to the cooperator in the test-method.

Calling the `addStudent()` method in your test-method should fix the problem.

```
@Test
public void cooperatorStudent() {
    String studentID = "260632353";
    String firstname = "Saleh";
    String lastname = "Bakhit";
    Student student1 = service.createStudent(studentID, firstname, lastname, cooperator);
    assertEquals(cooperator, student1.getCooperator());

    studentID = "260632350";
    firstname = "testFirst";
    lastname = "testLast";
    Student student2 = service.createStudent(studentID, firstname, lastname, cooperator);
    assertEquals(cooperator, student2.getCooperator());

    cooperator.addStudent(student1);
    cooperator.addStudent(student2);

    Set<Student> cooperatorStudents = cooperator.getStudent();
    assertTrue(cooperatorStudents.contains(student1));
    assertTrue(cooperatorStudents.contains(student2));
}
```

Comment: I do add it in the create student method.. see the edit in the post for the code

Comment: Can you provide the code for this method: `studentRepository.save(student);` ?